# How to remove element from an array of dict?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a dictionary array `records`

```
async def execute_query(query):
    async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
        async with conn.cursor() as cur:
            await cur.execute(query)
            records = []
            async for row in cur:
                records.append({
                    'id':    row[0],
                    'created_at': row[1],
                    ...
                })

    return records;
```

I want to return all records except elements(dicts) that have 
`id` = 1.
How to do this quickly? I don't want to add `if else` statement inside loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It's a list comprehension that filters out the elements you don't want.

```
async for row in [x for x in cur if x['id'] != 1 ]:
    records.append....
```

Of course you can move the list comprehension onto it's own line if you think that's clearer. The disadvantage of this approach though is that it creates a new list containing all the items you want from 'cur'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use List comprehension:

```
return [record for record in records if record['id'] != 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I think list comprehension is faster in this case, not sure if it's even possible without an if statement

```
records = [{'id':1,'created_at':0},
           {'id':0,'created_at':0}
           ]
ones = [d for d in records if d['id']!=1]
print (ones)
```

prints:

```
[{'id': 0, 'created_at': 0}]
```

if you want to change records:

```
records = [d for d in records if d['id']!=1]
print (records)
```

prints:

```
[{'id': 0, 'created_at': 0}]
```

or as others are saying with the return statement:

```
return [d for d in records if d['id']!=1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return_records = []
for r in records:
    for key, value in r.items():
        while key == 'id' and value != 1:
            return_records.append(r)
            break
return return_records

(OR)
tmp_record = records
for r in tmp_record:
    for key, value in r.items():
        while key == 'id' and value == 1:
            records.remove(r)
            break
return records
```

Comment: you should provide an explanation instead of only raw code.

Comment: - Above code is without using any if else condition.